Upgrade Front Door Classic to Premium/Standard with terraform
I currently have a FrontDoor Classic production which is maintained by terraform. I would like to upgrade to standard/Premium with terraform with no downtime and using terraform How is this achievable using the least effort?

The following guide does guide does mention how such a resource upgrade can be done via the portal but not by terraform
Can we create a brand new front door and have two in parallel, then simply switch over? I do not think this will work since I guess a URL can only be pointed to a single front door
Do we need to upgrade via the portal then import the terraform resources? If so we all know that terraform is not the best tool for importing resources.
Another conclusion is the Frontdoor classic uses different terraform modules so upgrading via the portal will mean all the terraform code will stop working. Am I right?

Thank you


Upgrade Front Door Classic to Premium/Standard with terraform: -

Firstly, as you have mentioned, migrating from classic to standard/premium via portal would be done and a very easy process. It can be done by changing configuration under a classic front door and click on upgrade.
However, according to your requirement, using terraform will make things a little bit tough.
Steps include:
After setting up the provider and related terraform configurations, import the existed front door classic custom domain configuration into terraform state file first.
Resource provider for front door classic - azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration.
Once it is imported, create a front door standard/premium with the classic front door configuration as you imported. In this way, you will be able to upgrade it through terraform. But with this process, there might be compatibility or configurations issues that could affect the migration.
terraform import azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration.main /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/mygroup1/providers/Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/xxx/customHttpsConfiguration/xxx

Note: Saying that, azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration resource is deprecating and will not be able to migrate it using terraform further. For this, service team has providing a Migration tool as detailed in the above document.
I would recommend you use portal or migration tool for upgrading classic to standard/premium.
